# keep MessageCenter alive when app remove from recent

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a background scheduler that will send data on server periodically. for that i have created service in android which will send message to `Xamarin.Forms` using `MessageCenter` after 1 min so that it can send data to the server.

code related to Sending data to server is resides into `Xamarin.Forms` hence i am communicating via `MessageCenter` from `Xamarin.android` to `Xamarin.Forms`

it works well when the app is in foreground but when i remove app from recent.

`MessageCenter` subscribed in `Xamarin.Forms` dies hence when service in `Xamarin.Android` post event to `Xamarin.Forms` there is no one listen there and due to that my data is not getting posted on sever.

Xamarin.Forms code to subscribe MessageCenter

```
 public void subscribeSyncScheduler()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IMessage, EventType>(this, RestApi.SYNC_SCHEDULER_EVENT, (sender, arg) =>
            {

                //SYNC DATA TO SERVER



            });

        }
```

service is posing event to Xamarin.Forms

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, "Sync: Service gets called ");


            MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage, EventType>(this, RestApi.SYNC_SCHEDULER_EVENT, null);

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161128152111/http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/)

Use Android Background service & iOS background threading
using Dependency Service to run task even after app minimized or killed

Comment: They too are using MessageCenter and app gets removed then code written in that article wont work so this link didnt help me

Comment: It is not necessary to use MessagingCenter you can call platform specific method from portable project using Dependency Service (refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17284/call-platform-apis-via-shared-services for Dependency Service example)

Comment: so you mean to say that if i use EventHandlers then it wont die when i will remove my application from recent ?

Comment: Once you start android service through Dependency Service. Service will continue running in background even if you kill your app from recent.

Comment: i have already told that i have no problem in running service , my service is running even if i am removing my app from recent. Problem is when i remove the app and service is sending data to forms there is nothing in forms that would listen at that time bcoz MessageCenter object will died at that time